# htaccess mod_rewrite redirection if a specific string in it

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some weird stuff left in my urls by old developers and would like to fix it by 301 redirection. I would like to redirect all urls with perpage/www.domain.com bit in it i.e.

`http://www.example.com/products/golf-clubs/Package-Sets/price/under100/grid/perpage/www.domain.com`

to

`http://www.example.com/products/golf-clubs/Package-Sets/price/under100/grid/`

So literally redirect all urls which contains `perpage/www.domain.com` to the version without it.

any ideas ?

cheers,
/Marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)/perpage/www\.domain\.com/?$ $1/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: for some reason getting - Internal Server Error 500, looks like .com ending in urls throws those errors, any ideas ?

Comment: I have actually tested it successfully before posting. Can you pls check your error.log and see what is matching error for this?